# Why was it called the breastplate of judgement? (Exodus 28:15)

Tags: exodus

Exodus 28:15-21 NKJV

**The Breastplate**

> 15 “You shall make the **breastplate of judgment.** Artistically woven
> according to the workmanship of the ephod you shall make it: of gold,
> blue, purple, and scarlet thread, and fine woven linen, you shall make
> it. 16 It shall be doubled into a square: a span shall be its length,
> and a span shall be its width. 17 And you shall put settings of stones
> in it, four rows of stones: The first row shall be a sardius, a
> topaz, and an emerald; this shall be the first row; 18 the second row
> shall be a turquoise, a sapphire, and a diamond; 19 the third row, a
> jacinth, an agate, and an amethyst; 20 and the fourth row, a
> beryl, an onyx, and a jasper. They shall be set in gold
> settings. 21 And the stones shall have the names of the sons of
> Israel, twelve according to their names, like the engravings of a
> signet, each one with its own name; they shall be according to the
> twelve tribes.

[Truth&Tidings](https://truthandtidings.com/2004/02/tabernacle-studies-the-garments-of-the-high-priest/) states:

> It was called the “breastplate of judgment” because it contained the
> means by which God’s judgments or decrees were revealed.

That doesn't clarify things for me. So my question is this: **Why was this called the breastplate of judgment?**

Answer (score 1):

There are also several records stating that the Urim and Thummim, part of the breast plate/ephod (on the shoulder straps) could be designed to answer divine questions about God's will:

- Num 27:21 - And he shall stand before Eleazar the priest, who shall inquire for him by the **judgment of the Urim** before the LORD. At his word they shall go out, and at his word they shall come in, both he and all the people of Israel with him, the whole congregation.”
- Deut 33:8 - Concerning Levi he said: “Give Your Thummim to Levi and Your Urim to Your godly one, whom You tested at Massah and contested at the waters of Meribah.
- 1 Sam 23:6, 9, 10 - (Now Abiathar son of Ahimelek had brought the ephod down with him when he fled to David at Keilah.) ... When David learned that Saul was plotting evil against him, he said to Abiathar the priest, “Bring the ephod.” And David said, “O LORD, God of Israel, Your servant has heard that Saul intends to come to Keilah and destroy the city on my account.
- 1 Sam 30:7, 8 - Then David said to Abiathar the priest, the son of Ahimelech, “Bring me the ephod.” So Abiathar brought it to him, 8and David inquired of the LORD: “Should I pursue these raiders? Will I overtake them?” “Pursue them,” the LORD replied, “for you will surely overtake them and rescue the captives.”

[1 Sam 14:8 is another highly debatable instance that might be the subject of another question.]

Thus, the ephod/breatplate was used to make judgements via the Urim and Thummim on its shoulder straps.  hence it was called the "**"breastplate of judgment"**

The commonly held view is that these two objects, Urim and Thummim were probably semi-precious stones used to answer yes/no questions of the LORD.  More than this we cannot say because almost nothing is recorded.

Comment: +1. Thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 1):

The object referred to as the "breastplate of judgement" was translated by the NIV as the "breastplate for making decisions". In this breastplate, the Urim and Thummim symbolizing divine decisions made in response to inquiries from people.

On the Sefaria.org website (ref Exodus 28:30), Rashi explains how the Urim and Thummim functioned to arrive at divine decisions;

> This was an inscription of the Proper Name of God which was placed between the folds (i. e. the two pieces forming the front and back) of the breast-plate through which it (the breast-plate) made its statements clear (lit., illuminated its words; מאיר from אור, light, this being an allusion to the אורים) and its promises true (מתמם from the root תמם, an allusion to תמים) (Yoma 73b). In the second Temple there was certainly the breast-plate (although other objects employed in the Temple Service were missing) for it was impossible that the High Priest should have lacked a garment, but that Divine Name was not within it. It was on account of the inscription which constituted the Urim and Thummim and which enabled it to give decisions that it was called “judgment”, as it is said, (Numbers 27:21) “And he shall enquire for him by the judgment of the Urim” (Numbers 27:21).

In Ezra 2:63 and Nehemiah 7:65, it is recorded that "The governor, therefore, ordered them not to eat any of the most sacred food until there should be a priest ministering with the Urim and Thummim". This statement suggests that both Urim and Thummim were lost, likely during the period when the Holy Temple was destroyed in 587BC.

Comment: Based on these explanations, I feel like the NIV translates it in a way that makes more sense. +1